# How to get IP address using q language

Tags: kdb

I am very new to q language and trying to get my IP address using system commands. I can get it in this format `127 0 0 1i` using function

```
getIP:{"i"$0x0 vs .z.a}
```

But I need the answer to be in this format: `127.0.0.1`.

Casting it to a symbol will not give me a dot format. So I must be using the wrong system command or wrong parsing!

Comment: Example for your problem is already mentioned on kx wiki:  https://code.kx.com/q/ref/casting/#vs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `.z.a` to get the ip address but it returns as an integer as you know. To get it in the format you want you can use

```
`$"." sv string 256 vs .z.a
```

where `256 vs .z.a` turns it to the number base 256 and `sv` joins the returned numbers with a dot.

The ability to use a base with `vs` was added in v3.4 2015.12.13 and so won't work on an earlier version. You can check your version using `.z.K`. If you are using an earlier version then you can substitute `256` with `"h"$0x0`.

You can read more here: https://code.kx.com/q/ref/casting/#vs

Comment: your code is exactly as it is in the documents and I copy and paste but I get this error: k){x\:y}
'nyi
@
256\:
2130706433i

Comment: What is the return of .z.K?

Comment: 3.3 is the return of .z.K

Comment: In this case use `$"." sv string "h"$0x0 vs .z.a

Comment: Perfect. Is this to do with the version of q? I like to accept this solution. Should I tick on the original or you like to put the latest one?

Answer (score 1):

Note that you can also make system calls to the machine to determine it's environment. Generally speaking anything you can find from a linux prompt you can also find in kdb via system calls.

```
q)system"hostname -i"
"12.345.6.789"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the Hostname from .z.h , and pass the value from it get the IP address

```
`$"." sv string 256 vs  .Q.addr .z.h
```